# Custom ComboBox Selection display

Tags: c#, wpf, image, combobox

I currently have a custom made combobox allowing to choose an image from its drop down and display the image inside the toggle button of the combobox. It works fine but I have one problem. If i set my currently selected item from code or xaml(with selectedIndex for example), the display of the image in the button is wrong(Only half the image appears in the button). If i selected it manually by going through the drop down it works fine(the image is stretched to the button size). In fact, simply clicking on the drop down seems to fix the problem.

My question is, what exactly happens when you click on the togglebutton of a combobox. That way i can replicate it and make it work.

Image: http://postimg.org/image/tlwg0gdq3/

```
<ComboBox Name="Spell1ComboBox" Style="{StaticResource SpellComboBox}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Width="55" DockPanel.Dock="Left" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
<controls:MyComboBoxItem Tag="Rage" Description="Le mode rage augmente considérablement la cadence de tir du vaisseau." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <Image Source="/AsteroidsInterface;component/Media/spell1.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill"/>
</controls:MyComboBoxItem>
<controls:MyComboBoxItem Tag="Chaîne" Description="Créer une chaîne laser entre les deux joueurs pour 5 secondes. Tout les astéroides entrant en contact avec la chaine sont détruits. Si un seul joueur est présent, celle-ci s'attache à la station la plus proche." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Image Source="/AsteroidsInterface;component/Media/spell2.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
</controls:MyComboBoxItem>
<controls:MyComboBoxItem Tag="Bouclier" Description="Le vaisseau devient invulnérable et détruit les astéroides avec lesquelles il entre en contact." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" >
    <Image Source="/AsteroidsInterface;component/Media/spell3.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
</controls:MyComboBoxItem>
<controls:MyComboBoxItem Tag="Réparation" Description="Les tirs du joueur peuvent redonner des points de vie aux stations. Peux être combiné avec rage pour augmenter l'efficacité. " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
    <Image Source="/AsteroidsInterface;component/Media/spell4.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
</controls:MyComboBoxItem>
<controls:MyComboBoxItem Tag="Téléportation" Description="Permet au vaisseau de se téléporter dans la direction qu'il face." Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
    <Image Source="/AsteroidsInterface;component/Media/spell5.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
</controls:MyComboBoxItem>
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:MyComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:MyComboBoxItem">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        Padding="0"
                        Height="50" 
                        Width="50"
                        Margin="0"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        CornerRadius="0"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="Orange" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup"
                             Placement="Right"
                             HorizontalOffset="-4"
                             IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=Border, Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             AllowsTransparency="True"
                             Focusable="False"
                             PopupAnimation="None">
                        <DockPanel Background="Orange" Width="100">
                            <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Bold" DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Label>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Description}" 
                                               Foreground="Black" 
                                               FontSize="10"
                                               DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                               Padding="10,3,3,3"></TextBlock>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource UltimateBlueBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="SpellComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid Height="60" Width="55">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Orange" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="55"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border
                          x:Name="Border"
                          Grid.RowSpan="2"
                          CornerRadius="5"
                          BorderBrush="{StaticResource UltimateBlueBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="0" >
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource UltimateBlue}"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <Border 
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          Width="55"
                          Height="55"
                          CornerRadius="5"
                          BorderBrush="Transparent"
                          BorderThickness="2">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Border>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <Path x:Name="Arrow"     
                                  Width="5"
                                  Height="3"
                                  Fill="Orange"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="SpellComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="60"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="55"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton
                                Name="ToggleButton"
                                Style="{StaticResource SpellComboBoxToggleButton}"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Focusable="false"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                ClickMode="Press">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Name="ContentSite"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >                                
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup"
                             Placement="Bottom"
                             HorizontalOffset="-5"
                             VerticalOffset="-3"
                             IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                             AllowsTransparency="True"
                             Focusable="False"
                             PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                              MinWidth="174"
                              MinHeight="116"
                              MaxHeight="116">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="5">
                                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange" />
                                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange" />
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <Grid Margin="2,2,2,2" IsItemsHost="True" 
                                                 KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                            <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Could you post some images to illustrate the symptom? upload them to some website and provide the links, I can help you import them into Stackoverflow.

Comment: Also, post your relevant XAML markup and code (if any).

Comment: I don't know why a combobox would have a toggle button, seems that's not a default property. But here are the events a combobox generates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox_events(v=vs.110).aspx Typically these event's can be triggered from code if you want to test them.

Comment: added code and screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't add comments yet, but does calling invalidate() manually inside your code also show the full image? 
If it is, maybe loading your image to the checkbox is being done asynchronously while invalidate() is first called when the loading haven't even finished, 
And then the loading is asynchronously finished so everytime the view is refreshed after the initial draw it works fine.
It's just an assumption.

Comment: I tried calling invalidate after setting the selected index from code, still get the same problem. The image doesnt stretch

Comment: Hmm can i see how you are loading your image to the combo box toggle button through code ?

Comment: its in the code above, image is the content of comboboxitem, passed to the toggle button in the style using a contentpresenter in spellcombobox

Comment: Can you try setting the horizontalcontentalignment and verticalcontentalignment of the togglebutton to stretch?

Comment: I did, i get the same problem

Comment: That isn't an answer and it should be deleted.